# How to move time 3 hours ahead?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my current part of the select query:

```
replace(Convert(VARCHAR(20), tablename.Created, 120), ' ', ' | ')
```

and I want to move the time 3 hours forward.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is going to fail so much. But well, to answer your question, have a look at the `dateadd` function.

Comment: sth like this ? `replace(Convert(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(HOUR, 3, tablename.Created), 120), ' ', ' | ')`

Comment: use [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186819.aspx)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about something trivial to find on the internet and in the SQL Server documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
replace(Convert(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(HOUR, 3, tablename.Created), 120), ' ', ' | ')
```